# Multiple Parameters Windows Command Line

Tags: windows, batch-file

Good morning everyone!

I remember there was a way to do this back in the day, but haven't had to use it in so long that I can't remember how.

What I need is to be able to do the following without interaction, if at all possible:

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS

REM Change to the Cortex Directory
CD "C:\Program Files\Change_to_a_directory_here"

REM Temporarily Disable Cortex
cytool runtime stop && ThisIsThePasswordINeedToSend

REM Change to Repository Directory
D:

REM Run Repository GUI
RunThisProgram.exe

REM This restarts Cortex
cytool runtime start
```

Now when typing the password, it doesn't echo anything on the screen.

Isn't there a way to get that done?

Thanks!

Comment: Try either `(echo ThisIsThePasswordINeedToSend) | cytool runtime stop`.